# Sorting char array in ascending order (with Link list)

Tags: linked-list

I want to arrange my link list (which contains char arrays) in ascending order. This program should allow the user to input some names and then display them in ascending order. I have used the strncpy function. There are no compilation errors.But instead of names, the output gives some integers (perharps addresses). Please help me! I am new to C!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

char name [10];


struct node
{
char nm [10];
struct node *next;
}*newnode, *prev, *temp, *display, *current, *list;

void createlist()
{
list=NULL;
};

void insert ()
{
newnode=(struct node*) malloc (sizeof (struct node));

printf("Enter the Name: ");
scanf("%s",&name);
strncpy(newnode->nm,name, 10);
newnode->next=NULL;

if (list==NULL)
{
    list=newnode;
}
else if (name<list->nm)
{
    newnode->next=list;
    list=newnode;
}
else
{
    temp=list;
    int place;
    place=0;

    while (temp!=NULL && place ==0)
    {
        if (name>temp->nm)
        {
            prev=temp;
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        else
        {
            place=1;
        }
        newnode->next=prev->next;
        prev->next=newnode;
    }
}
}

void displayname()
{
if (list==NULL)
    printf("\n\nList is empty");
else
{
    display=list;
    while(display!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n",display->nm);
        display=display->next;
    }
}
 }

 int main()
 {

char choice;
choice=='y';

createlist();
do
{
    insert ();
    printf("Do you want to continue? ");
    scanf("%s",&choice);
}while (choice='y'&& choice!='n');

displayname();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the display function you have

```
printf("%d\n",display->nm);
```

The %d formatter outputs the argument as an integer.  Use printf's %s formatter to get character arrays

```
printf("%s\n",display->nm);
```

You will still need to write the sorting code ... put the problem of outputtin numbers instead of text.